# Composition or inheritance

Tags: php, inheritance, design-patterns, composition

```
interface DoSomething
{
    public function do();
    public function getId();
}

class DoSomethingGood implements DoSomething 
{
    private $dependency;

    private $id;

    public function __construct($id, $dependency)
    {
        $this->dependency = $dependency;
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function do()
    {
        if ($this->dependency->isActive()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}

class DoSomethingBad implements DoSomething 
{
    private $id;

    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function do()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Should I be using composition here or would inheritance be better?  The difference is in how these classes implement the `do()` method.  The first class has a dependency it requires and some internal logic to decide whereas the other is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

The inheritance is a semantic relationship. Not the composition. A common mistake is to factorize code by using inheritance instead of composition.

just see [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: amazing insight, please put some links to books, articles that you liked on your profile, i really wonder what can make one think like this.

Comment: @Arjang Take a look at the basic principles of OO design: [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))

Answer (score 1):

I think you should think conceptually about this code. What is the relationship between those classes? Is it an *is-a* relationship or a *has-a* relationship?

If you can say `DoSomethingGood` *is a* `DoSomething`, then inheritance reflects this well. You can have the inheritor substitute the inherited class and proper polymorphism. The rest of the application will flow well with this choice because it reflects how you think about it.

If you can say `DoSomething` *has a* `DoSomethingGood` then you should use composition. Especially if you can *have many* `DoSomethingGood`. Again, if this is conceptually correct, the rest of the code is easy to write.

Sometimes it looks like you can say "yes" to both and the lines blur, but you should really think about it at the conceptual level, not at the code level. Especially if you want to understand patterns and not just "code reuse", which is a diminutive way of reasoning about inheritance.

When your choice is wrong, coding will become cumbesome, counter-intuitive, unnecessarily complex or plain out impossible (contradictory). If that happens get back to the drawing board and rethink your choices.

That said, you are pretty much the only person that can say what you have in mind and what you want to do. If you use names like `DoSomethingGood` it's ambiguous.

It's much easier when you say `Cat`, `Dog` and `Animal`. Here it's pretty easy to say what to use (the assertion "`Cat` *is a* `Animal`" is intuitively correct).